# plotly marker size relative to data to plot interactive wafer map

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to create interactive wafer maps with python unsing plotly. The plot shall show the different categorical bins of the single chips e.g. bin 1 all good chips, bin 2 all fails... Now the problem, when i use `px.scatter(...)` i get all the nice functionality with mouse over and a dynamic legend that i want but the single chips don't align:

[image: dynamic but not aligned].

I tried `go.layout.Shape(...)` - then i get what I want visually but loose the interactivity:

[image: aligned but now dynamic].

Plotly documentation kind of points out this trade-off between shapes and traces (https://plotly.com/python/shapes/).

Any suggestions? Can i rescale plot markers accordingly when I read out the axis ranges and know the image size? one problem might be, that sometimes chips are not quadratic but just rectangular - can i pass an aspect ratio to the marker?

Maybe plotly aint the right tool for what i want?

Comment: Plotly shapes unfortunately don't have any interactivity. You should be able to eliminate the padding between the pixels since both axes are categorical. Alternatively, using a `heatmap` might work for the type of chart you are trying to create

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish the desired chart using a `heatmap` which is basically a specialized scatter plot with categorical axes, and colors for different values.

I don't know the exact format of your data, but I downloaded [a dataset of wafer maps from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/qingyi/wm811k-wafer-map/download), where the first column of the DataFrame contains a 2D array, and each row is a unique wafer. You can then pass any of the 2D arrays directly as an argument to `px.imshow` and get a heatmap:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("LSWMD.pkl")
wafer = df.iloc[0,0]

fig = px.imshow(wafer)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nice response. I falsly ruled imshow out because i thought it can only supports continous data. But as far as I have read it should also support discrete values for the color legend: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2642 , https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3468 . I havent figured out how to implement it yet but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on something similar and constraining the axis on the plot fixed the spacing issue. Try something like:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    range=[0, 300],
    title_text="X (mm)",
    title_font={"size": 12},
    scaleanchor='y',
    scaleratio=1)

fig.update_yaxes(
    range=[0, 300],
    title_text="Y (mm)",
    title_font={"size": 12},
    scaleanchor="x")
```

This will cause the plot axis to have a 1:1 aspect ratio with axis constrained at 0-300 mm. Hopefully this will make the markers line up better.

You can also ask the user to input die dimensions and use that to size your markers when you initialize the plots.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little further... I can stack multiple traces of heatmaps now but I still miss the clickable legend - the initial reason to go with plotly. I used abstract data now to simplify.

One could adjust the go.Heatmap object to change its legend but that is beyond my scope. What i tried is to use buttons but they dont work consistently (when used initially they sometimes need 2 clicks) and I cannot change the colour of individual buttons (only off a set of buttons, but it would be close to impossible to align e.g. 20 sets nicely). Any suggestions?

PS: How can I post my html version of the graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

demo_matrix = np.empty((3,3))
demo_matrix[:] = np.nan
demo_matrix[1,1] = 1
demo_matrix[1,2] = 2
demo_matrix

fig = make_subplots()

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=np.where(demo_matrix!=1, np.nan, demo_matrix),colorscale = [[0, 'blue'], [1, 'blue']], hoverinfo='skip'))
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=np.where(demo_matrix!=2, np.nan, demo_matrix),colorscale = [[0, 'red'], [1, 'red']], hoverinfo='skip'))

#trace for hover info - not perfect yet
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=demo_matrix,colorscale = [[0, 'red'], [1, 'red']],opacity=0))

fig.update_traces(showscale=False)

button_1 = dict(
    method='restyle',
    label="red",
    visible=True,
    args=[{'visible':True}, [1]],
    args2 = [{'visible': False}, [1]],
)

button_2 = dict(
    method='restyle',
    label="blue",
    visible=True,
    args=[{'visible':True}, [0]],
    args2 = [{'visible': False}, [0]],
)

button_3 = dict(
    method='restyle',
    label="all",
    visible=True,
    args=[{'visible':True}],
    args2 = [{'visible': False}],
)

fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500,
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type = "buttons",
            direction = "left",
            buttons=[button_1,button_2, button_3],
            pad={"r": 5, "t": 5},
            showactive=False,
            x=.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top",
            bgcolor = '#AAAAAA',
            bordercolor = '#FFFFFF',
            font=dict(color="red")
        ),
    ]
)
fig.show()
fig.write_html("test.html")
```